# Count number of sheets to the left or tab with highest date in its name

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that has a template. Now day I'll duplicate this tab to create a new one. Then I have to adjust a start date based on the what week it is. Because I create this every 2 weeks, I was wondering if there is a way to get a count of tabs to the left. If I can then I just need to look at start date on my template and add day based on how many weeks its been as each tab will represent 2 weeks.

If this is not possible, is it possible then to instead get the name of the lat tab and convert it to a date? Then I can add 2 weeks to that date. My tab names are just basically dates (02-25-2018).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
function createSheet() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getSheets()//get all the sheets
  var len=s.length// how many sheets
  var name=s[len-1].getSheetName()//get name of last sheet
  var newSheet=new Date(name)//convert to date
  var newdate = newSheet.setDate(newSheet.getDate()+14);//add 14 days to date
  var twoWeekDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(newdate), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy")//set format
   ss.insertSheet(twoWeekDate)//create new sheet
  }
```

Comment: I believe this is a script, I'm trying to do it within the Google Spreadsheet with an `=` command.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest more general solution then your task.

Here's the function to get all tabs names:

```
function getAllTabsNames()
{
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = file.getSheets();
  var result = [];
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet) { result.push(sheet.getName()); } );
  return result;
}
```

Usage:

`=IF(A1,getAllTabsNames())`

Note:

- The function does not refresh automatically when the new sheet appears. To refresh it manually, use this trick. Write `TRUE` in cell `A1`, then change it to `FALSE` and to `TRUE` again.

[image]

The result is the array: list of names of sheets.

Your next steps:

- use native functions to get the desired result.